# Why Am I Seeing Output as Octet-Stream in Logic Apps?

Tags: http, azure-logic-apps

In my Logic App, I call an XML REST API using an HTTP connector. The output of the HTTP connector is displayed as Octet-Stream. But I know from my Postman call that the API returns XML.

[image]

I know how to handle this issue. I put a Set Variable component after HTTP and set the variable to the output value which is an XML this time - I don't apply any explicit transformation.

[image]

I just want to know what would cause the HTTP connector to output Octet-Stream and if there is a smarter way to handle the issue. Even I added the same headers in the Postman call to the Logic Apps HTTP, but this didn't work.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic Apps always preserves the `Content-Type` in a received HTTP request or response. So if your logic app receives content with `Content-Type` set to `application/octet-stream`, and you include that content in a later action without casting, the outgoing request also has `Content-Type` set to `application/octet-stream`. That way, Logic Apps can guarantee that data doesn't get lost while moving through the workflow. However, the action state, or inputs and outputs, is stored in a JSON object while the state moves through the workflow.

[image]

In a response connector you can add a header as Content-Type as application/xml

To preserve some data types, Logic Apps converts content to a binary base64-encoded string with appropriate metadata that preserves both the `$content` payload and the `$content-type`, which are automatically converted.

`xml()`  Casts data to `application/xml`

Refer for [converter-functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-content-type#converter-functions)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. First, I already set a temporary variable to the output of the xml() method in my case. But this doesn't meet my need. I hoped to get rid of the extra casting operation by only using the HTTP control. You say that it is impossible, and we always need another operation to cast the output. Second, the Response control after an HTTP control with a trigger is not allowed. The error message: "The workflow with 'Response' action type should not have triggers with 'recurrence' property defined: 'HTTP'". I see that there is no way to get rid of the extra cast operation.